# Inconsistent Function Deparsing in R

Tags: r, function, matrix

I've made a **Augmented Coefficient Matrix** function to solve systems of linear equations and I've encountered some inconsistencies on deparsing functions in R using the `deparse()` function.

**Input:**

```
yield4 <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) 153.7 * x1 + 94.2 * x2 + 79.5 * x3 + 200 * x4 + 200 * x5 + -298.3
yield5 <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) 144.2 * x1 + 91.5 * x2 + 78.2 * x3 + 137.3 * x4 + 200 * x5 + -288.7

deparse(yield4)
deparse(yield5)
```

**Output:**

```
> deparse(yield4)
[1] "function (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) "                                   
[2] "153.7 * x1 + 94.2 * x2 + 79.5 * x3 + 200 * x4 + 200 * x5 + -298.3"
> deparse(yield5)
[1] "function (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) "                               
[2] "144.2 * x1 + 91.5 * x2 + 78.2 * x3 + 137.3 * x4 + 200 * x5 + "
[3] "    -288.7"
```

As you can see, whenever I run that script, for some reason deparsing yield5 returns a character of 3 elements wherein deparsing other functions results in only 2 elements. This breaks the program I created for the AugCoeffMatrix. Anyone knows why R does this?

**I've already tried the following:**

- Rewriting the function (Same Issue)
- Changing the function name (Same Issue)
- Removed all the function spaces (Same Issue)
- Added curly braces (Same Issue)
- Changing the constant value (Same Issue)
- Changed last sign operators (Same Issue)

**EDIT:** Adjusting the width.cutoff of the function parameters to a higher integer value fixed the issue.

Comment: try with this: `deparse(yield5, width.cutoff = 100L)`

Comment: `deparse(yield5, width.cutoff = 500)` but you probably should compute on the language instead of deparsing.

Comment: @DaveCordero Note that this is not really a fix. If your function body gets wider, the cutoff is applied again.

Comment: @Roland Yeah, I know that very well. I could alter the function to allow more than 2 character elements as arguments but I think this solution is already within the scope of which our professors wants from us. (This is not a practical way of solving systems of linear equations in the first place)

Comment: I rather suspect that "in real life" doing a `deparse` here is not a great approach.  How about using `formals`  and `body` instead?    That is to say,  "What is the problem you are trying to solve?" ask that instead of asking why a specific approach has trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `deparse1` (R 4.0+):

```
deparse1(yield4)
## [1] "function (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)  153.7 * x1 + 94.2 * x2 + 79.5 * x3 + 200 * x4 + 200 * x5 + -298.3"

deparse1(yield5)
## [1] "function (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)  144.2 * x1 + 91.5 * x2 + 78.2 * x3 + 137.3 * x4 + 200 * x5 + -288.7"
```

Comment: And pre-4.0, you can define it yourself: `function (expr, collapse = " ", width.cutoff = 500L, ...) paste(deparse(expr, width.cutoff, ...), collapse = collapse)`